# What is the difference between service and JobService

Tags: android, service, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I am wondering what is the main difference between service and JobService in Android.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613494/what-is-a-jobservice-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Service is the parent class in Android Studio and JobService is the child or base class.

```
      <service android:name="MyJobService"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >
     ...
 </service>
```